# .htaccess RewriteRule help

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have successfully set up an URL system that redirects shortcuts like this:

```
# http://www.site.com/102/ -> http://www.site.com/102-some-keywords.html
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3})/?$ includes/redirect.php?ref=$1 [L]
# http://www.site.com/102-some-keywords.html -> http://www.site.com/templates/default/index.php?ref=102
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3})-.*?\.html$ templates/default/index.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

Now I am upgrading to a multi language system and want to get the language code right after the domain:

```
# http://www.site.com/fr/102/ -> http://www.site.com/fr/102-some-keywords.html
# http://www.site.com/fr/102-some-keywords.html -> http://www.site.com/templates/default/index.php?loc=fr&ref=102
```

some languages are fr, it, es, ru,...
I guess I need multiple variables $1, $2 but I am stuck with this part.

Here is a try (not working correctly)

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(^[0-9]{3})/?$ includes/redirect.php?loc=$1&ref=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(^[0-9]{3})-.*?\.html$ templates/default/index.php?loc=$1&ref=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new code is basically correct, except that you forgot the `^` (match start of expression) before `[0-9]`. Just removing those should make the code work, but I'd personally add stricter matching for the country code: `[a-z]{2}`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{3})/?$ includes/redirect.php?loc=$1&ref=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{3})-.*?\.html$ templates/default/index.php?loc=$1&ref=$2 [L]
```